# How to set LogLevel to error in log4net for hangfire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, hangfire

We have a web application and we are using log4net for logging. Recently I installed hangfire and now my log table (sqlserver db) is full of log enteries from hangfire. I want to minimise this to error and exceptions only. I believe I can set it by setting LogLevel to error but where exactly I need to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this logger to your web.config (log4net section)

```
<logger additivity="false" name="Hangfire">
   <level value="ERROR" />
   <appender-ref ref="HangfireLoggerAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Its working on my local. Once it works on production I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Martino Bordin Thanks

Comment: more detail and an example for NLog are on the hangfire discussion forum https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/log4net-logging/1280/2

Comment: how to set value to level node if I want both "Debug" and "ERROR" levels?

Comment: just remember to set your own appender name used in log4net configuration in tag <appender-ref ref="..." /> shown in the answer above.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what @Martino mentioned above here is the exact location to add that tag in log4net section:

```
<log4net debug="true">
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger additivity="false" name="Hangfire">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="HangfireLoggerAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```